# Ghost button for Pie menu

Tags: python, scripting, interface, add-on, pie-menu

Pie menus work sorting / placing the buttons as it seems via
82467913

but this is not idea specifically when you have less buttons than 8.

Is there a way to create invisible place holder buttons so for example slot 1 and 3 are not used but only 4 7 8 9 6  and 2

In the image below I split show and hide mesh up into two sections.
I would prefer Show Mesh to be just empty.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pie menu items are filled in a specific order - first the left item then the right, the bottom item then the top, then the top diagonals and the bottom diagonals are filled last. If the numbers used for each position seems odd for this layout compare them to your numeric keypad.

The primary design of the pie menus is to place one menu item at each location. As we have found this can be abused to show many items at each location.

While items are added in order to specific locations, we can effectively 'skip' an item by having a label with no text taking the position we want blank, it will need to be followed by a call to `menu_pie()` to make the next item to go to the next position otherwise it will be positioned with the label.

```
pie = pie.row()
pie.label('')
pie = layout.menu_pie()
```

Comment: I tried this out but this does not work. I pasted at the empty positions your code examples.

Comment: Sorry I missed that I had a `row()` or `column()` before the label when I was experimenting.

Comment: Could we get this in the official pie menu docs? This is absurdly helpful.